# Rust blog backend in Rocket and Diesel, lots of clones

Tags: rust

I have a small blog backend in Rust with Rocket and Diesel on Postgres. It reads and writes to and from the database fine, but to get to where it is I used a lot of `clone()` calls on strings. I feel like it could be written more efficiently with lifetimes, but my grasp of lifetimes in Rust is quite tenuous and I get a lot of compiler complaints.

The blog is divided into collections called 'atlases' with sub pages in each atlas. Each page has properties including ancestors, content blocks, and user IDs and roles. Each request comes with a cookie containing a session ID. To get a page the program receives a POST request to an endpoint containing an atlas ID and a page ID. It uses the cookie to authenticate the request, then queries the database through a Diesel schema to get the content blocks, ancestors, and other bits and bobs belonging to the page, and returns them as JSON data.

The `main.rs` file is generally standard Rocket boilerplate. The relevant bits for the POST handler to get a page from an atlas:

```
mod atlas;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_contrib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use response::{ResponseJson, ResponsePublicMedia, ResponseStaticFile, STATIC_FILES};
use rocket::http::CookieJar;
use rocket::Data;

pub mod schema;

#[database("postgres_conn")]
pub struct Db(diesel::PgConnection);

... // various endpoints and handlers

#[post("/endpoint/atlas.page.get/<atlas_id>/<page_id>")]
async fn tel_atlas_page_get(
    conn: Db,
    cookies: &CookieJar<'_>,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
) -> ResponseJson {
    atlas::page_get(conn, cookies, atlas_id, page_id).await
}

...

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount(
            "/",
            routes![
                ...
                tel_atlas_page_get,
                ...
            ],
        )
        .attach(Db::fairing())
}
```

The handler internals file:

```
use crate::atlas;
use crate::response::ResponseJson;
use crate::users::auth;
use crate::utilities::ERR;
use crate::Db;

use rocket::http::CookieJar;
use rocket_contrib::databases::diesel::prelude::*;

pub async fn page_get(
    conn: Db,
    cookies: &CookieJar<'_>,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
) -> ResponseJson {
    // Page data
    let a_clone_page = atlas_id.clone();
    let p_clone_page = page_id.clone();
    let page = match conn.run(|c| get_page(c, a_clone_page, p_clone_page)).await {
        Some(p) => p,
        None => return ResponseJson::message("page.404", ""),
    };

    // User ID
    let user_id = match cookies.get("token") {
        Some(cookie) => match auth::check(cookie).await {
            Some((_email, user_id, _name, _token)) => Some(user_id),
            None => None,
        },
        None => None,
    };

    // Atlas role
    let a_clone_role = atlas_id.clone();
    let role = match user_id.clone() {
        Some(u) => conn.run(|c| get_atlas_role(c, u, a_clone_role)).await,
        None => "none".to_owned(),
    };

    // Page users
    let a_clone_users = atlas_id.clone();
    let p_clone_users = page_id.clone();
    let users = match user_id.clone() {
        Some(u) => {
            conn.run(|c| get_users(c, u, a_clone_users, p_clone_users))
                .await
        }
        None => Vec::new(),
    };

    if page.public || role != "none" || (user_id.is_some() && !users.is_empty()) {
        // Page ancestors
        let a_clone_ancestors = atlas_id.clone();
        let p_clone_ancestors = page_id.clone();
        let ancestors = conn
            .run(|c| get_ancestors(c, a_clone_ancestors, p_clone_ancestors))
            .await;

        // Page children
        let a_clone_children = atlas_id.clone();
        let p_clone_children = page_id.clone();
        let children = conn
            .run(|c| get_children(c, a_clone_children, p_clone_children))
            .await;

        // Page blocks
        let timestamp_clone = page.timestamp.clone();
        let blocks = conn
            .run(|c| get_blocks(c, atlas_id, page_id, timestamp_clone))
            .await;

        // JSON encode
        let page_encoded = match serde_json::to_string(&page) {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(_) => return ResponseJson::error(ERR.generic),
        };
        let users_encoded = match serde_json::to_string(&users) {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(_) => return ResponseJson::error(ERR.generic),
        };
        let ancestors_encoded = match serde_json::to_string(&ancestors) {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(_) => return ResponseJson::error(ERR.generic),
        };
        let children_encoded = match serde_json::to_string(&children) {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(_) => return ResponseJson::error(ERR.generic),
        };
        let blocks_encoded = match serde_json::to_string(&blocks) {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(_) => return ResponseJson::error(ERR.generic),
        };
        ResponseJson::message(
            "atlas.page",
            &format!(
                "{{\"page\":{},\"atlas_role\":\"{}\",\"users\":{},\"ancestors\":{},\"blocks\":{},\"children\":{}}}",
                page_encoded, role, users_encoded, ancestors_encoded, blocks_encoded, children_encoded
            ),
        )
    } else {
        ResponseJson::message("auth.forbidden", "")
    }
}

fn get_page(
    conn: &mut diesel::PgConnection,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
) -> Option<atlas::Page> {
    use crate::schema::atlas_pages;

    if &page_id == "maps" || &page_id == "locations" {
        match atlas_pages::table
            .select((
                atlas_pages::page_id,
                atlas_pages::atlas_id,
                atlas_pages::title,
                atlas_pages::image,
                atlas_pages::public,
                atlas_pages::parent,
                atlas_pages::timestamp,
            ))
            .filter(atlas_pages::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
            .filter(atlas_pages::page_id.eq("index"))
            .first::<atlas::Page>(conn)
        {
            Ok(a) => Some(atlas::Page {
                page_id,
                atlas_id,
                title: a.title,
                image: a.image,
                public: a.public,
                parent: "index".to_owned(),
                timestamp: a.timestamp,
            }),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    } else {
        match atlas_pages::table
            .select((
                atlas_pages::page_id,
                atlas_pages::atlas_id,
                atlas_pages::title,
                atlas_pages::image,
                atlas_pages::public,
                atlas_pages::parent,
                atlas_pages::timestamp,
            ))
            .filter(atlas_pages::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
            .filter(atlas_pages::page_id.eq(&page_id))
            .first::<atlas::Page>(conn)
        {
            Ok(a) => Some(a),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}

fn get_users(
    conn: &mut diesel::PgConnection,
    user_id: String,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
) -> Vec<atlas::AtlasUser> {
    use crate::schema::page_users;

    let user = match page_users::table
        .select((page_users::user_id, page_users::user_type))
        .filter(page_users::user_id.eq(&user_id))
        .filter(page_users::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
        .filter(page_users::page_id.eq(&page_id))
        .first::<atlas::AtlasUser>(conn)
    {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(_) => return Vec::new(),
    };

    if user.user_type == "owner" {
        match page_users::table
            .select((page_users::user_id, page_users::user_type))
            .filter(page_users::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
            .filter(page_users::page_id.eq(&page_id))
            .load::<atlas::AtlasUser>(conn)
        {
            Ok(a) => a,
            Err(_) => Vec::new(),
        }
    } else {
        vec![user]
    }
}

fn get_atlas_role(conn: &mut diesel::PgConnection, user_id: String, atlas_id: String) -> String {
    use crate::schema::page_users;

    match page_users::table
        .select((page_users::user_id, page_users::user_type))
        .filter(page_users::user_id.eq(&user_id))
        .filter(page_users::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
        .filter(page_users::page_id.eq("index"))
        .first::<atlas::AtlasUser>(conn)
    {
        Ok(a) => a.user_type,
        Err(_) => "none".to_owned(),
    }
}

fn get_ancestors(
    conn: &mut diesel::PgConnection,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
) -> Vec<atlas::Ancestors> {
    use crate::schema::page_ancestors;

    match page_ancestors::table
        .select((
            page_ancestors::page_id,
            page_ancestors::atlas_id,
            page_ancestors::title,
            page_ancestors::index,
            page_ancestors::ancestor,
        ))
        .filter(page_ancestors::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
        .filter(page_ancestors::page_id.eq(&page_id))
        .order(page_ancestors::index.asc())
        .load::<atlas::Ancestors>(conn)
    {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(_) => Vec::new(),
    }
}

fn get_children(
    conn: &mut diesel::PgConnection,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
) -> Vec<atlas::Page> {
    use crate::schema::atlas_pages;

    match atlas_pages::table
        .select((
            atlas_pages::page_id,
            atlas_pages::atlas_id,
            atlas_pages::title,
            atlas_pages::image,
            atlas_pages::public,
            atlas_pages::parent,
            atlas_pages::timestamp,
        ))
        .filter(atlas_pages::atlas_id.eq(&atlas_id))
        .filter(atlas_pages::parent.eq(&page_id))
        .order(atlas_pages::title.desc())
        .load::<atlas::Page>(conn)
    {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(_) => Vec::new(),
    }
}

fn get_blocks(
    conn: &mut diesel::PgConnection,
    atlas_id: String,
    page_id: String,
    timestamp: String,
) -> Vec<atlas::Block> {
    use crate::schema::page_blocks;

    match page_blocks::table
        .select((
            page_blocks::page_id,
            page_blocks::atlas_id,
            page_blocks::index,
            page_blocks::label,
            page_blocks::block,
            page_blocks::text,
            page_blocks::data,
            page_blocks::timestamp,
        ))
        .filter(page_blocks::atlas_id.eq(atlas_id))
        .filter(page_blocks::page_id.eq(page_id))
        .filter(page_blocks::timestamp.eq(timestamp))
        .order(page_blocks::index.asc())
        .load::<atlas::Block>(conn)
    {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(_) => Vec::new(),
    }
}
```